# Animate (fade) out shape on mouseup/touch off

Tags: fabricjs

I've been trying to learn fabric.js and am having a hard time figuring out how to target/select the shape i've just added on `mouse:down`, so that i can fade it out on `mouse:up`.

What i have so far: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygjr3m4L/2/)

```js
var fingerCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var fingerMark = new fabric.Ellipse({
  left: -100,
  top: -100,
  fill: '#ff0000',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  rx: 35,
  ry: 50
});

//fingerCanvas.add(fingerMark);

fingerCanvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
  fingerMark.top = obj.e.y;
  fingerMark.left = obj.e.x;
  //fingerCanvas.renderAll();
});

fingerCanvas.on('mouse:down', function(obj) {
  fingerCanvas.add(fingerMark.clone());
  //fingerCanvas.renderAll();
});

fingerCanvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
  //fade out the ellipse added by mouse:down event
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Anyone familiar with fabricjs and is able to point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In animate method, give `opacity` property to animate and value to 0.

Added abort method to stop animation, if user clicking again in between 1 second.

***DEMO***

```js
var fingerCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});
var fingerMark = new fabric.Ellipse({
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  fill: '#ff0000',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  rx: 35,
  ry: 50,
  evented: false,
  opacity: 0
});
var isMouseDown = false;

fingerCanvas.add(fingerMark);

fingerCanvas.on('mouse:move', function(options) {
  if (isMouseDown) {
    var pointer = fingerCanvas.getPointer(options.e);
    fingerMark.set({
      left: pointer.x,
      top: pointer.y
    })
    fingerCanvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
});

fingerCanvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
  isMouseDown = true;
  var pointer = fingerCanvas.getPointer(options.e);
  fingerMark.set({
    opacity: 1,
    left: pointer.x,
    top: pointer.y
  });
});

fingerCanvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
  isMouseDown = false;
  fingerMark.animate('opacity', 0, {
    duration: 1000,
    abort: function() {
      return isMouseDown;
    },
    onChange: fingerCanvas.requestRenderAll.bind(fingerCanvas),
    onComplete: function() {
      fingerMark.set({
        opacity: isMouseDown ? 1 : 0
      });
      fingerCanvas.requestRenderAll();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is fantastic, i banged my head for hours, but this  makes sense. Thank you